I have a get API which is supposed to return an excel file to download on the frontend
On fetching this API, it is returning the following headers with the content-disposition: form-data
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
vary: Origin, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers
content-disposition: form-data; name="attachment"; filename="tenant_report.xlsx"
accept-ranges: bytes
x-content-type-options: nosniff
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
cache-control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
pragma: no-cache
expires: 0
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
content-type: application/octet-stream
content-length: 3965
date: Tue, 23 Apr 2024 08:11:17 GMT
connection: close

In the Network tab, the response tab is empty, however it is showing the binary data in the Preview tab, below is the screenshot
Network preview tab:

On fetching this API in React.js, it is directly jumping to the catch block. The backend is on springboot java
I am using the following code to fetch and then download the xlsx file, but it is jumping to the catch block and returning the object with the message: "status not exist in body". Am I handling the data right way?
const downloadFile = (fileData, filename) => {
    const blob = new Blob([fileData], { type: 'application/octet-stream' });
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    console.log("THIS IS URL", url)
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = url;
    link.setAttribute('download', filename);
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
  };

  async function downloadBill() {
    try {
      const params = {
        fromYear: currentYear,
        fromMonth: currentMonth,
        toYear: currentYear,
        toMonth: currentMonth,
        buildingId: buildingId,
        tenantId: 229
      }
      const response = await billing.downloadTenantMonthlyBill(params)
      console.log("REPSONSE", response)
      const { data, headers } = response;
      console.log("THIS IS DATA and HEADERS", { data, headers })
      const filename = headers['content-disposition'].split('filename=')[1]; // Extract filename from content-disposition header
      downloadFile(data, filename);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error downloading file:', error.message);
    }
  }

The billing GET API is like this :
async function downloadTenantMonthlyBill({ fromYear, fromMonth, toYear, toMonth, buildingId, tenantId }) {
  const params = {
    fromYear: fromYear,
    fromMonth: fromMonth,
    toYear: toYear,
    toMonth: toMonth,
    buildingId: buildingId,
    tenantId: tenantId
  };
  return await axiosApi.get(`${urlPath}/downloadTenantMonthlyBilling`, { params, responseType: 'blob' });
}


blob is not going to work, just try using responesType: arrayBuffer I think it was called, I remember it has the name array, and the encoding would not look gibberish, and then simply do a download. For some reason idk why blob does not work these days, so that's why I am writing this as a comment
